# What is the correct use of value in HTML form inputs?

Tags: html, forms, input, textarea

If I make an input or textarea with a value attribute, when a user enters some info in that input, will the value submitted to the server change?

If this is the case, does "value" just serve as an initial placeholder that behaves slightly differently than the "placeholder" attribute?

For example if I have `<input type="text" name="color" value="red" placehold="blue">` and the user enters `orange`, what will actually gets submitted in the form's POST?

Comment: you want to know that the value already present in the form get posted to server?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and Yes.

In HTML, a `placeholder` is "fake" text. Clicking in the box to begin typing will cause the placeholder to dissapear. A `value`, however, is real text; it represents the default value of the input. If an input has a `placeholder` and the user does not interact with it, an empty input will be submitted. If an input has a `value`, however, that value will be submitted.

In the case of your example, `orange` is submitted. In fact, the `placeholder` is meaningless unless the user empties the text box.

Comment: So if a user enters a value, it overrides the value attribute?

Comment: Yes; the `value` only represents the initial contents of the box. The user can change them.

Answer (score 2):

HTML `<textarea>` tags do not have a valid `value=""` attribute.

That said, yes, if a user changes an input value, it will be sent as-is during form submission. `placeholder=""` is an HTML5 attribute that does not affect the value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The value is a default value for that element; it provides the initial value, and if the user doesn't change it, that value will be submitted to the server. For some form controls, such as radio buttons and checkboxes, the value is the value that will be provided to the server if that checkbox or radio button is submitted.

A placeholder is just text that is drawn inside the control, but will never be submitted to the server. It is essentially a different way of giving a label for the control, that happens to show up inside the control. If you have only a placeholder, and the user submits without entering anything, the value submitted will be empty.

For your example, `orange` will be submitted via the POST; if the user doesn't change the value, then "red" would be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If I understood you correctly then YES the `value` attribute if is already set and the form is submitted then the value of the input would be posted to the server exchange.

In addition to your example, `orange` will be submitted because `placeholder` is just a piece of text which is temporary. A `value` will be the original text of the input.

According to w3schools:

> The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the
>   expected value of an input field
>
> The value attribute specifies the value of an `<input>` element.

One more thing, in your example first `red` is set as the value. Without changing anything you submit the form then `red` will be submitted but if you change it to `orange` orange will be submitted AND `placeholder` will have no effect as its a text that dissapers when we focus on that particular `<input>`

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field (e.g. a sample value or a short description of the expected format).

The short hint is displayed in the input field before the user enters a value.

Note: The placeholder attribute works with the following input types: text, search, url, tel, email, and password.

check it here
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp